# Get Bluetooth name of the device and the connected bluetooth in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bluetooth

I'd like to get the name of the iPhone's bluetooth and eventually the name of scanned bluetooth devices that the iPhone detects. Any indication of how to do  that in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, [this](https://github.com/ruiking/ble) is the best example, but it is in *Objective-C*. It won't be difficult for you to translate the project to *Swift*. Spend some time and understand the example. It is a very good example. Currently, there are a lot of good examples in *Objective-C*, but only a few in *Swift*. You may also have a look at [this](https://github.com/barsuga/techbeacon). It is a simple *Swift* project about *Bluetooth & iBeacon*. Good luck! :)